# Extract video tag poster URL only

Tags: php, regex

I just want to extract the poster attribute value of video tag by using regex.

```
<video id="my-video" controls="controls" poster=https://example.com><source src=https://example.com&oauth2_token_id=xxxxxx type="video/mp4"></video>
```

This is my video tag. How can I achieve this using regex in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: You need to start with valid html... How about showing the actual source you're working with

Comment: `poster`'s value lacks of quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?<=(poster=))([\w+\:\/\.]+)
```

`(?<=)` is called lookbehind. it matches pattern IF condition is fulfilled

EDIT:

Or if your value will be quoted:

```
(?<=(poster="))([\w+\:\/\.]+)
```